# How to fix all Nuget references in a .net core solution quickly?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package-restore

I am finding it a common issue where when I download a .NET repo from Github, the solution has missing references. See an example below.  When using Nuget Package Manager, it says the packages are installed already. The packages folder is missing.

I tried using 'Update-Package -reinstall' and got a bunch of lines with 'No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'project name'.... That's probably due to the missing package files.

I can fix each reference manually but it's a time consuming process. Is there a way to force fix all these references in all the projects in one swoop using a command or a tool that 'cleverly' knows what to do? I am using Visual Studio 2019 16.3 preview 1

[image]

Comment: To comment on two points, the packages folder is only used by `packages.config` projects. SDK style projects (this is SDK because it has a "dependencies" node in the tree, not "references") only supports `PackageReference`, which does not use a packages folder. `Update-Package -reinstall` also only supports `packages.config`, which is why it doesn't do anything.

Comment: delete obj folder and reopen the solution

Comment: Hi Tony, any update for this issue:)

Comment: What I did is manually remove one of the references and add it back and suddenly the rest of them got fixed. Thanks for the info you posted.

Comment: Please verify the NuGet.config in the root folder. Ensure that the key value pairs inside  <packageSources> node are correct. If not please add  <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />

Answer (score 2):

In VS2019, those .net core projects or .net standard projects use [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) instead of [packages.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config) format to manage nuget packages. And in this way, the content in xx.csproj looks similar to this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="8.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Every time you download a project which uses packageReference format, you only get the xx.csproj and related source files but without nuget packages. So when you open and load the solution or project in VS IDE, it will display the `nuget packages` name in `solution explorer` but with `yellow warning triangle` since now VS can't find those packages locally.

> Is there a way to force fix all these references in all the projects
> in one swoop using a command or a tool that 'cleverly' knows what to
> do?

Just like what **zivkan** said in his answer, **NuGet is normally configured to restore packages automatically if you've enabled those two options.** Every time when we load the soultion in IDE, it will automatically restore the packages for us. Not sure the reason why it seems not to work in your machine, but you can check and try:

1.Go `Nuget Package Manager`=>`Package Sources`, make sure you've set `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` as one the `Available Package sources.`

2.Right-click the solution in `Solution Explorer`, choose the `Restore Nuget Packages` to restore packages for whole solution.

3.Or you can Unload and reload the project to check if it helps.

4.By default, the packages are stored at `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages` folder, you can check if those folders exists there.

(I delate all packages in that folder, so it's clear when I open the git solution in VS, the nuget is installing those necessary packages automatically, I'm not sure if there's any possibility that cause too many packages are being installed,so it will take some time? I check and find, `to restore necessary packages` for `NorthWind` solution, it require packages for over 370 MB)

> I tried using 'Update-Package -reinstall' and got a bunch of lines
> with 'No package updates are available from the current package source
> for project 'project name'.... That's probably due to the missing
> package files.

And for the reason why `Update-Package -reinstall` not work well in the project, maybe it's a similar issue like [nuget issue #4103](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4103), for the `packagereference` in xx.csproj, several commands for now are not supported.

And after my check in my machine, the command obviously do **not work** for a `PackageReference-format` .net standard project. When I've installed related packages **successfully**, I run this command but only get `No package updates are available from the current package source for project xxx`, then I **delete** the installed packages, clean the cache and run the command again, I still get same message!

So I think this command can't recognize `PackageReference` format in .csproj, no matter whether I install related packages or not,  it will always throw message `No package updates are available ...`

Comment: I'm using Git on my CentOS VPS server which I've configured to run asp.net core, and after committing on my local PC I'm pulling the changes on my server and building the project using `dotnet` command line, how can I fix the references in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

NuGet is normally configured to restore packages automatically. See the options page. The second Package Restore option, "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio" is enabled by default on clean installs.

[image: Visual Studio Options with NuGet Package Manager, General open]

Here's a little video I recorded of what happens on my machine when I open the solution. Keep an eye out on the status bar at the bottom left of the window.

[image: video of opening the solution, the status bar updating and quickly changing to say "restore complete", and expanding the project dependencies to see there are several NuGet packages installed in the project, with no warning icon]

If your installation of Visual Studio does not behave in the same way with the automatic restore option enabled, then there is some other issue on your machine, but we don't have enough information from your question, as of the time I wrote this.

Comment: Those two options are already enabled. I am already doing a update-package manually so those options have no effect whether they're off or on.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich in that case, you haven't provided enough information for me to help. Does your VS get the "restore completed" message in the status bar? Does the "package manager" output contain any messages? Does restoring from the command line give any messages? does your `obj/project.assets.json` have an error section? What do you mean by "manually fix" in your question?